# Angularjs determine which tab(directive) is being presented to the user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

If I have lets say 5 tabs with each displaying a different directive, is there a way to determine which tab I am being presented? I need a way to hide certain tabs depending on which tab is being viewed. Hopefully an easy way with a built in angular method or jquery? I can only think of adding an object that stores which tab was last clicked or something.

Comment: are you using ui-bootstrap? Or did you write your own directive?

Answer (score 0):

Set a tab index variable when each tab is clicked (`ng-click="selectedTab = 1"`) and then show/hide tabs or content based on which tab is currently selected (`ng-show="selectedTab == 1"`). These built-in directives just evaluate an expression, so you can get more creative in the way you use them if you want. For example:

- `ng-hide="selectedTab == 2 || selectedTab == 5"`
- `ng-show="selectedTab > 3 && selectedTab % 2 == 0"`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to avoid but ended up doing anyways, I only had to keep track of a single tab and had to create a method just to store that one value. Was really hoping there is some angular or jquery method to check what directive(tab) was selected.

Comment: There is an AngularUI Bootstrap directive for tabs that you should take a look at ([http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)), but the above solution is simple enough for most implementations.